# How can I find out if I caused a mixed content warning?

Tags: javascript, security, warnings, mixed

I am trying to find and log any instances where I create a mixed content warning on someone's browser. Is there a way I can programmatically inspect for these security warnings? I'll take any hack I can get, including browser specific ones. I need to show 3rd party content on my https site I want to verify that none of the content is causing security issues.

Comment: Do you need to do that at runtime or once at design time?

Comment: Continuously during runtime.

Comment: It is unlikely you'll find solution (as you can't inspect content of third party IFrame via script, can't block third party script from creating elements pointing to http content and browsers don't exposes any network statistics/shiffig to page's script). But someone may know something - keep hope :)

Comment: I know this is old, but there is now this Desktop app that will scan an entire site for mixed content: https://www.ecommerce.co.uk/httpschecker , hope it's of use for you or someone.